# PostgreSQL on IBM Cloud Kubernetes returns "psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "replica_user"" error. Works on GCP and Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ibm-cloud

I have deployed this PostgreSQL image to the IBM Cloud, Google Cloud Platform and Microsoft Azure using Kubernetes. https://github.com/paunin/PostDock

It was successfully deployed on all 3 platforms with identical configurations and an identical process. The IBM cloud fails with the error "psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "replica_user""

You can find below the logs from all 3 cloud platforms. Has anyone experienced this?

### IBM Cloud Log

```
>>> Setting up STOP handlers...
>>> STARTING SSH (if required)...
>>> SSH is not enabled!
>>> STARTING POSTGRES...
>>> TUNING UP POSTGRES...
>>> Cleaning data folder which might have some garbage...
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "replica_user"
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "cyclos-postgres-node2-service" (172.30.65.206) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>>> Auto-detected master name: ''
>>> Setting up repmgr...
>>> Setting up repmgr config file '/etc/repmgr.conf'...
>>> Setting up upstream node...
cat: /var/lib/postgresql/data/standby.lock: No such file or directory
>>> Previously Locked standby upstream node LOCKED_STANDBY=''
>>> Waiting for upstream postgres server...
>>> Wait db replica_db on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432(user: replica_user,password: *******), will try 30 times with delay 10 seconds (TIMEOUT=300)
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "replica_user"
>>>>>> Db replica_db is still not accessable on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432 (will try 30 times more)
....
```

The last couple of lines are then repeated many times.

This is the log file from deploying the same application, using identical processes on the Google Cloud. It works just fine on the Google Cloud Platform.

### Google Cloud Log

```
>>> Setting up STOP handlers...
>>> STARTING SSH (if required)...
>>> SSH is not enabled!
>>> STARTING POSTGRES...
>>> TUNING UP POSTGRES...
>>> Cleaning data folder which might have some garbage...
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "cyclos-postgres-node1-service" (10.52.0.11) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "cyclos-postgres-node2-service" (10.52.0.12) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>>> Auto-detected master name: ''
>>> Setting up repmgr...
>>> Setting up repmgr config file '/etc/repmgr.conf'...
>>> Setting up upstream node...
cat: /var/lib/postgresql/data/standby.lock: No such file or directory
>>> Previously Locked standby upstream node LOCKED_STANDBY=''
>>> Waiting for upstream postgres server...
>>> Wait db replica_db on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432(user: replica_user,password: *******), will try 30 times with delay 10 seconds (TIMEOUT=300)
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "cyclos-postgres-node1-service" (10.52.0.11) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>>>>>> Db replica_db is still not accessable on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432 (will try 30 times more)
>>>>>> Db replica_db is still not accessable on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432 (will try 29 times more)
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "cyclos-postgres-node1-service" (10.52.0.11) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "cyclos-postgres-node1-service" (10.52.0.11) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>>>>>> Db replica_db is still not accessable on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432 (will try 28 times more)
>>>>>> Db replica_db exists on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432!
>>> REPLICATION_UPSTREAM_NODE_ID=1
>>> Sending in background postgres start...
>>> Waiting for upstream postgres server...
>>> Wait db replica_db on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432(user: replica_user,password: *******), will try 30 times with delay 10 seconds (TIMEOUT=300)
>>>>>> Db replica_db exists on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432!
>>> Starting standby node...
>>> Instance hasn't been set up yet.
>>> Clonning primary node...
>>> Waiting for upstream postgres server...
>>> Wait db replica_db on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432(user: replica_user,password: *******), will try 30 times with delay 10 seconds (TIMEOUT=300)
NOTICE: destination directory '/var/lib/postgresql/data' provided
INFO: connecting to upstream node
INFO: Successfully connected to upstream node. Current installation size is 34 MB
INFO: checking and correcting permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ...
>>>>>> Db replica_db exists on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432!
NOTICE: starting backup (using pg_basebackup)...
INFO: executing: '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_basebackup -l "repmgr base backup"  -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -h cyclos-postgres-node1-service -p 5432 -U replica_user -c fast -X stream '
NOTICE: standby clone (using pg_basebackup) complete
NOTICE: you can now start your PostgreSQL server
HINT: for example : pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data start
HINT: After starting the server, you need to register this standby with "repmgr standby register"
[REPMGR EVENT] Node id: 2; Event type: standby_clone; Success [1|0]: 1; Time: 2018-02-02 13:24:32.87843+00;  Details: Cloned from host 'cyclos-postgres-node1-service', port 5432; backup method: pg_basebackup; --force: Y
>>> Configuring /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
>>>>>> Will add configs to exists file
>>> Starting postgres...
>>> Waiting for local postgres server start...
>>> Wait db replica_db on cyclos-postgres-node2-service:5432(user: replica_user,password: *******), will try 60 times with delay 10 seconds (TIMEOUT=600)
LOG:  incomplete startup packet
LOG:  incomplete startup packet
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-02-02 13:24:31 UTC
FATAL:  the database system is starting up
psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
>>>>>> Db replica_db is still not accessable on cyclos-postgres-node2-service:5432 (will try 60 times more)
LOG:  entering standby mode
LOG:  redo starts at 0/2000028
LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/20000F8
LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 0/3000000 on timeline 1
>>>>>> Db replica_db exists on cyclos-postgres-node2-service:5432!
>>> Waiting for replication on this node is over(if any in progress): CLEAN_UP_ON_FAIL=, INTERVAL=30
>>> Replication is done
>>> Unregister the node if it was done before
DELETE 0
>>> Registering node with role standby
INFO: connecting to standby database
INFO: connecting to master database
INFO: retrieving node list for cluster 'postgres_cluster'
INFO: registering the standby
[REPMGR EVENT] Node id: 2; Event type: standby_register; Success [1|0]: 1; Time: 2018-02-02 13:24:51.891592+00;  Details: 
INFO: standby registration complete
NOTICE: standby node correctly registered for cluster postgres_cluster with id 2 (conninfo: user=replica_user password=replica_pass host=cyclos-postgres-node2-service dbname=replica_db port=5432 connect_timeout=2)
 Locking standby (NEW_UPSTREAM_NODE_ID=1)...
>>> Starting repmgr daemon...
[2018-02-02 13:24:53] [NOTICE] looking for configuration file in current directory
[2018-02-02 13:24:53] [NOTICE] looking for configuration file in /etc
[2018-02-02 13:24:53] [NOTICE] configuration file found at: /etc/repmgr.conf
[2018-02-02 13:24:53] [INFO] connecting to database 'user=replica_user password=replica_pass host=cyclos-postgres-node2-service dbname=replica_db port=5432 connect_timeout=2'
[2018-02-02 13:24:53] [INFO] connected to database, checking its state
[2018-02-02 13:24:53] [INFO] connecting to master node of cluster 'postgres_cluster'
[2018-02-02 13:24:53] [INFO] retrieving node list for cluster 'postgres_cluster'
[2018-02-02 13:24:53] [INFO] checking role of cluster node '1'
[2018-02-02 13:24:53] [INFO] checking cluster configuration with schema 'repmgr_postgres_cluster'
[2018-02-02 13:24:53] [INFO] checking node 2 in cluster 'postgres_cluster'
[2018-02-02 13:24:53] [INFO] reloading configuration file
[2018-02-02 13:24:53] [INFO] configuration has not changed
[2018-02-02 13:24:53] [INFO] starting continuous standby node monitoring
ERROR:  cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction
STATEMENT:  DELETE FROM repmgr_postgres_cluster.repl_nodes WHERE conninfo LIKE '%host=cyclos-postgres-node3-service%'
```

And on the Azure Cloud, it works just fine as well.

### Azure Cloud Log

```
>>> Setting up STOP handlers...
>>> STARTING SSH (if required)...
>>> SSH is not enabled!
>>> STARTING POSTGRES...
>>> TUNING UP POSTGRES...
>>> Cleaning data folder which might have some garbage...
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "cyclos-postgres-node2-service" (10.244.0.9) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>>> Auto-detected master name: 'cyclos-postgres-node1-service'
>>> Setting up repmgr...
>>> Setting up repmgr config file '/etc/repmgr.conf'...
>>> Setting up upstream node...
cat: /var/lib/postgresql/data/standby.lock: No such file or directory
>>> Previously Locked standby upstream node LOCKED_STANDBY=''
>>> Waiting for upstream postgres server...
>>> Wait db replica_db on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432(user: replica_user,password: *******), will try 30 times with delay 10 seconds (TIMEOUT=300)
>>>>>> Db replica_db exists on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432!
>>> REPLICATION_UPSTREAM_NODE_ID=1
>>> Sending in background postgres start...
>>> Waiting for upstream postgres server...
>>> Wait db replica_db on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432(user: replica_user,password: *******), will try 30 times with delay 10 seconds (TIMEOUT=300)
>>>>>> Db replica_db exists on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432!
>>> Starting standby node...
>>> Instance hasn't been set up yet.
>>> Clonning primary node...
>>> Waiting for upstream postgres server...
>>> Wait db replica_db on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432(user: replica_user,password: *******), will try 30 times with delay 10 seconds (TIMEOUT=300)
NOTICE: destination directory '/var/lib/postgresql/data' provided
INFO: connecting to upstream node
>>>>>> Db replica_db exists on cyclos-postgres-node1-service:5432!
INFO: Successfully connected to upstream node. Current installation size is 34 MB
INFO: checking and correcting permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ...
NOTICE: starting backup (using pg_basebackup)...
INFO: executing: '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_basebackup -l "repmgr base backup"  -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -h cyclos-postgres-node1-service -p 5432 -U replica_user -c fast -X stream '
NOTICE: standby clone (using pg_basebackup) complete
NOTICE: you can now start your PostgreSQL server
HINT: for example : pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data start
HINT: After starting the server, you need to register this standby with "repmgr standby register"
[REPMGR EVENT] Node id: 2; Event type: standby_clone; Success [1|0]: 1; Time: 2018-02-02 06:50:47.340146+00;  Details: Cloned from host 'cyclos-postgres-node1-service', port 5432; backup method: pg_basebackup; --force: Y
>>> Configuring /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
>>>>>> Will add configs to exists file
>>> Starting postgres...
>>> Waiting for local postgres server start...
>>> Wait db replica_db on cyclos-postgres-node2-service:5432(user: replica_user,password: *******), will try 60 times with delay 10 seconds (TIMEOUT=600)
LOG:  incomplete startup packet
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-02-02 06:50:46 UTC
LOG:  incomplete startup packet
FATAL:  the database system is starting up
psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
>>>>>> Db replica_db is still not accessable on cyclos-postgres-node2-service:5432 (will try 60 times more)
LOG:  entering standby mode
LOG:  redo starts at 0/2000028
LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/2000130
LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 0/3000000 on timeline 1
>>>>>> Db replica_db exists on cyclos-postgres-node2-service:5432!
>>> Waiting for replication on this node is over(if any in progress): CLEAN_UP_ON_FAIL=, INTERVAL=30
>>> Replication is done
>>> Unregister the node if it was done before
DELETE 0
>>> Registering node with role standby
INFO: connecting to standby database
INFO: connecting to master database
INFO: retrieving node list for cluster 'postgres_cluster'
INFO: registering the standby
[REPMGR EVENT] Node id: 2; Event type: standby_register; Success [1|0]: 1; Time: 2018-02-02 06:51:05.083455+00;  Details: 
INFO: standby registration complete
NOTICE: standby node correctly registered for cluster postgres_cluster with id 2 (conninfo: user=replica_user password=replica_pass host=cyclos-postgres-node2-service dbname=replica_db port=5432 connect_timeout=2)
 Locking standby (NEW_UPSTREAM_NODE_ID=1)...
>>> Starting repmgr daemon...
[2018-02-02 06:51:05] [NOTICE] looking for configuration file in current directory
[2018-02-02 06:51:05] [NOTICE] looking for configuration file in /etc
[2018-02-02 06:51:05] [NOTICE] configuration file found at: /etc/repmgr.conf
[2018-02-02 06:51:05] [INFO] connecting to database 'user=replica_user password=replica_pass host=cyclos-postgres-node2-service dbname=replica_db port=5432 connect_timeout=2'
[2018-02-02 06:51:06] [INFO] connected to database, checking its state
[2018-02-02 06:51:06] [INFO] connecting to master node of cluster 'postgres_cluster'
[2018-02-02 06:51:06] [INFO] retrieving node list for cluster 'postgres_cluster'
[2018-02-02 06:51:06] [INFO] checking role of cluster node '1'
[2018-02-02 06:51:06] [INFO] checking cluster configuration with schema 'repmgr_postgres_cluster'
[2018-02-02 06:51:06] [INFO] checking node 2 in cluster 'postgres_cluster'
[2018-02-02 06:51:06] [INFO] reloading configuration file
[2018-02-02 06:51:06] [INFO] configuration has not changed
[2018-02-02 06:51:06] [INFO] starting continuous standby node monitoring
ERROR:  cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction
STATEMENT:  DELETE FROM repmgr_postgres_cluster.repl_nodes WHERE conninfo LIKE '%host=cyclos-postgres-node3-service%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run this on a paid cluster in IBM Cloud and it appears to be working.  I did NOT use the persistent volumes and I was on a paid cluster.  Please note that persistent volumes are not available on free clusters, so if you are testing on a free cluster you will get issues if you use persistent volumes.

My cluster has 3 workers of size u2c.2x4 (the smallest available) and is on the default version of Kubernetes for IBM Cloud (1.8.6), if that helps you debug at all.  Please try again or if your setup is different than mine, let me know and I can try with a matching setup.

```
$ kubectl logs --namespace=mysystem mysystem-db-node1-0
>>> Setting up STOP handlers...
>>> STARTING SSH (if required)...
>>> SSH is not enabled!
>>> STARTING POSTGRES...
>>> TUNING UP POSTGRES...
>>> Cleaning data folder which might have some garbage...
psql: could not translate host name "mysystem-db-node1-service" to address: Name or service not known
psql: could not translate host name "mysystem-db-node2-service" to address: Name or service not known
>>> Auto-detected master name: ''
>>> Setting up repmgr...
>>> Setting up repmgr config file '/etc/repmgr.conf'...
>>> Setting up upstream node...
>>> Sending in background postgres start...
>>> Waiting for local postgres server start...
>>> Wait db replica_db on mysystem-db-node1-service:5432(user: replica_user,password: *******), will try 60 times with delay 10 seconds (TIMEOUT=600)
psql: could not translate host name "mysystem-db-node3-service" to address: Name or service not known
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "mysystem-db-node1-service" (172.30.207.54) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
selecting default shared_buffers ... >>>>>> Db replica_db is still not accessable on mysystem-db-node1-service:5432 (will try 60 times more)
128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
creating template1 database in /var/lib/postgresql/data/base/1 ... ok
initializing pg_authid ... ok
initializing dependencies ... ok
creating system views ... ok
loading system objects' descriptions ... ok
creating collations ... ok
creating conversions ... ok
creating dictionaries ... ok
setting privileges on built-in objects ... ok
creating information schema ... ok
loading PL/pgSQL server-side language ... ok
vacuuming database template1 ... ok
copying template1 to template0 ... ok
copying template1 to postgres ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start


WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
waiting for server to start....LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Cannot assign requested address
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-02-14 15:40:14 UTC
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
 done
server started
CREATE DATABASE

CREATE ROLE


/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/entrypoint.sh
>>> Configuring /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
>>>>>> Config file was replaced with standard one!
>>>>>> Adding config 'wal_keep_segments'='250' 
>>>>>> Adding config 'shared_buffers'='300MB' 
>>>>>> Adding config 'archive_command'=''/bin/true'' 
>>> Creating replication user 'replica_user'
CREATE ROLE
>>> Creating replication db 'replica_db'

LOG:  received fast shutdown request
LOG:  aborting any active transactions
LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
waiting for server to shut down....LOG:  shutting down
LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-02-14 15:40:16 UTC
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  incomplete startup packet
LOG:  incomplete startup packet
>>>>>> Db replica_db exists on mysystem-db-node1-service:5432!
>>> Registering node with role master
INFO: connecting to master database
INFO: master register: creating database objects inside the 'repmgr_mysystem_cluster' schema
INFO: retrieving node list for cluster 'mysystem_cluster'
[REPMGR EVENT] Node id: 1; Event type: master_register; Success [1|0]: 1; Time: 2018-02-14 15:40:27.337393+00;  Details: 
[REPMGR EVENT] will execute script '/usr/local/bin/cluster/repmgr/events/execs/master_register.sh' for the event
[REPMGR EVENT::master_register] Node id: 1; Event type: master_register; Success [1|0]: 1; Time: 2018-02-14 15:40:27.337393+00;  Details: 
[REPMGR EVENT::master_register] Locking master...
[REPMGR EVENT::master_register] Unlocking standby...
NOTICE: master node correctly registered for cluster 'mysystem_cluster' with id 1 (conninfo: user=replica_user password=replica_pass host=mysystem-db-node1-service dbname=replica_db port=5432 connect_timeout=2)
>>> Starting repmgr daemon...
[2018-02-14 15:40:27] [NOTICE] looking for configuration file in current directory
[2018-02-14 15:40:27] [NOTICE] looking for configuration file in /etc
[2018-02-14 15:40:27] [NOTICE] configuration file found at: /etc/repmgr.conf
[2018-02-14 15:40:27] [INFO] connecting to database 'user=replica_user password=replica_pass host=mysystem-db-node1-service dbname=replica_db port=5432 connect_timeout=2'
[2018-02-14 15:40:27] [INFO] connected to database, checking its state
[2018-02-14 15:40:27] [INFO] checking cluster configuration with schema 'repmgr_mysystem_cluster'
[2018-02-14 15:40:27] [INFO] checking node 1 in cluster 'mysystem_cluster'
[2018-02-14 15:40:27] [INFO] reloading configuration file
[2018-02-14 15:40:27] [INFO] configuration has not changed
[2018-02-14 15:40:27] [INFO] starting continuous master connection check
```